# CSS Class Selector won't work, but it works when I make it an ID?

Tags: css, class

This is very confusing. I have a CSS class that I want to add to a list item, but for some reason it won't appear when I assign it as a class, only when I assign it as an id. I obviously don't want that... because I want id's to be unique, but that seems to be the only thing that's working?

CSS:

```
.song-selection {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

HTML

```
<!---Set List Card-->
<div class="card-action">
  <h5 id='current-list'>Current Set List</h5>
  <h6 id="set-id-1" class="center">Set #1</h6>
  <hr>
  <ul class='collection set-1' id="set-1">
    <li class="collection-item song-selection">
      Live Wire (AC/DC)
    </li>
```

Comment: The weird thing is that if I change the CSS to something like "color: white" that rule works.

The background-color only seems to work when I assign an id... it's the weirdest thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because some other css rule takes priority. This could be due to [css specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) or the other rule being defined later in the css (then it takes priority also). If you add `!important` then it should override the other styles.

```
.song-selection {
background-color: gray !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

Comment: Bear in mind that `!important` is a useful diagnostic tool (it confirms that you're targeting the correct element), it's not a good long-term solution; instead you should simply increase the specificity of the selector or reduce the specificity of whatever selector is currently overriding your styles. I'd suggest reading about why we shouldn't use `!important`, for example: https://techrangers.cdl.ucf.edu/2018/09/10/css-specificity.html

Comment: @ChristopherGuyton please consider accepting the answer if the answer has solved your question and you do not need any additional help. Thanks!